# Background isn't working properly due to my table

Tags: html, css

So I have a basic table in HTML, and I added a background for the whole webpage via CSS.

But for some reason, this messes up my table like so:

How can I add a background, while keeping my table unaffected? 
Or, in other words, how do I add a background to my web page that contains a table, while still looking good?

My CSS:

```
body {
  background: url(intro-bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It is because your content's background is transparent. So why it is inheriting the background image. Try to give background to your content

Comment: oh ok, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, try adding `table { background: white; }`, or just add `background: white;` to the elements you want to have a white background instead of the body's background

Comment: Im actually trying to leave my table alone, and instead add a background for the web page.

Comment: If you apply a background image to `body`, it will be underneath every element on your page that doesn't have a background. There is no way to exclude the background from being under your table if you apply the background to `body`

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I know what you're looking for, but it looks like you need to add a background to the table cells.  something like:
    td { background: white; }